# which programs are using usb devices?

Tags: windows, delphi, usb, exe, usb-descriptor

How can I access the list of programs that are connected to usb devices ? In some cases my own software cannot open the usb device because it uses another program. I want to inform the user about which program to close.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903116/how-do-i-find-out-which-usb-devices-the-programs-use?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes i couldn't find a solution, they closed the topic.

Comment: You are not allowed to post the same question again. Instead, you should edit your old question. When a question is closed, it is because it is off-topic at SO or cannot reasonably be answered in a way that is in line with the SO rules. So if you ask the same Q again, naturally that Q will be closed for the same reason. That's why you should instead improve your old Q. If you do so, it can be reopened.

Comment: Please read the close message at the old Q. That message explains what is wrong with the question and what you can do to improve the question: "This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers. Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question."

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I fix it right away, thank you.